# ORACLE 11g UTL_SMTP and "Reply To" / "On Behalf Of"

Tags: oracle, email, smtp, oracle11g

We are using the `UTL_SMTP` package in ORACLE 11g to send emails from our system on behalf of the users.

It all gets sent out through a common SENDER account to validate against the SMTP server.

We'd LIKE for the emails to appear to come from the user who sent them through the system. 
Is there a way with the UTL_SMTP package to add one or both of the following properties to the emails sent:

REPLYTO - address to which replies to the message should be directed
ONBEHALFOF - I know Outlook lets you specify this when you send an email, then when the recipient gets it, it shows up as *from smtp account on behalf of other user*

I think the REPLYTO would be most important, so the recipients can respond to the users who sent the email, but it would be nice to have the ONBEHALFOF too.

Perusing the intellisense and documentation for the package though, I don't see any way to add either these. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [AskTom question](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3aNO%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1739411218448) for a way to do it. If there's a header for the "On Behalf Of" field, you should be able to do both, but the "Reply-To" is in the examples.

Here's [another example](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql.php) from Tim Hall's Oracle-Base site. See the "Multi Line Emails" section.

It pretty much amounts to brute force writing of the entire message envelope to the SMTP server.

Comment: Ah, thanks... that link gave me the info I needed to use the PARAMETERS argument of the `UTL_SMTP.mail` method as such: `UTL_SMTP.mail(oSMTP, idsystem.GETOPTION('SMTPUSR'), 'Reply-To=' || vSENDER);`. That then sends it out appearing as if it came from the sender's email.